# Swap the word and the numbers from a file and write a new file

Tags: python

How do I swap two items in a file which contains words on the left and numbers on the right?

I want to achieve numbers on the right and strings on the left.

I have a text file that contains huge numbers i.e corpus:

```
200 Apple
200 Banana
1 Hi
1 Hello
1112 Elevator
```

Comment: If this format is consistent, and if you're on a unix platform, then I think the `awk` command would be a much cleaner solution.  `awk '{print $2, $1}' < oldfile > newfile`

Comment: Is there always only ever one blank space on each line? If so, read it into pandas as a csv file (but specify space as the separator, and no header), then swap the columns and write it back out again.

Answer (score 0):

1. open file `f` for reading
2. open file `g` for writing
3. loop over all lines in file `f`:

   - split the line at the first space into parts `a` and `b`
   - concatenate parts `b` and `a` in swapped order with a space in between
   - write concatenated line to file `g`
4. close files `f` and `g`

Comment: If you have to close files, you're not using `with`, and if you're not using `with`, you're probably doing it wrong.

Comment: That's true. Using `with` to ensure closing files is preferred.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in 3 clean steps with a pandas dataframe.

1. read file
2. swap columns
3. write new file

so the code looks like this:

```py
import pandas as pd

# read into dataframe
data = pd.read_csv("some_file.txt", delimiter=" ", header=None)

# swap columns
data[0], data[1] = data[1], data[0]

# write data to a new file
data.to_csv("some_file_new.txt", header=False, index=False, sep = ' ')


print('file written !!')
```

and the new file contents looks like this:

```
Apple 200
Banana 200
Hi 1
Hello 1
Elevator 1112
```